# How do I do an initial push to a remote repository with Git?

Tags: git, version-control

I've read through countless tutorials and I keep coming up short. Here's what I've got:

- I'm running RubyMine on my Windows desktop
- I've installed Git on my WebFaction hosting account per their [instructions](http://docs.webfaction.com/software/git.html?highlight=git#create-a-place-to-store-git-repositories)
- Git appears to be working fine on both machines

Here's what I'm doing:

1. On server:

   - `mkdir project`
   - `git init`
   - `git add .`
   - `git commit   #==> nothing to commit`
2. On client:

   - Create new project in RubyMine
   - *Git init* in top directory of project
   - *Push changes* to server `#==> failed to push some refs to...`

What steps am I missing?

Answer (score 500, accepted):

On server:

```
mkdir my_project.git
cd my_project.git
git --bare init
```

On client:

```
mkdir my_project
cd my_project
touch .gitignore
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin youruser@yourserver.com:/path/to/my_project.git
git push origin master
```

Note that when you add the origin, there are several formats and schemas you could use. I recommend you see what your hosting service provides.

Comment: The only thing I changed, since I'm working out of RubyMine, is that I replaced the touch .gitignore with creating a rails project with its 66 default files.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Kudos for listing the commands. This is how I've set up remote repositories too.

Comment: I should add that if you want other people to collaborate with you on this repo, you should add `--shared` to the end of the `git --bare init` command. This will setup the necessary permissions.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It is very helpful to have stuff like this that fills in the missing stuff in what are very good books on git, but still don't cover a lot of conversion work from CVS.

Comment: I like to run `git push --set-upstream origin master` instead of `git push origin master` the first time.  This allows me to just type `git push` or `git pull` instead of `git push origin master` every time. Whatever fits your preferences.

Comment: Or set up an alias & just type something like gp.

Comment: This almost worked for me. The only thing that I had to add was the --set-upstream or -u flag for the git push origin master.
So when I changed to git push -u origin master it worked for me, thanks!

Comment: `git init --bare my_project.git` will create the folder for you and init inside.

Comment: Is that really necessary to do anything serverside? Could we just push to remote in order to create a brand-new remote repo?

Comment: i've been always pushing via `git push -u origin HEAD` - pushes your **current** branch to origin

Answer (score 10):

If your project doesn't have an upstream branch, that is if this is the very first time the remote repository is going to know about the branch created in your local repository the following command should work.

```
git push --set-upstream origin <branch-name>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try this:

on Server:

adding new group to `/etc/group` like
(example)

```
mygroup:1001:michael,nir
```

create new git repository:

```
mkdir /srv/git
cd /srv/git
mkdir project_dir
cd project_dir
git --bare init (initial git repository )
chgrp -R mygroup objects/ refs/ (change owner of directory )
chmod -R g+w objects/ refs/ (give permission write)
```

on Client:

```
mkdir my_project
cd my_project
touch .gitignore
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin youruser@yourserver.com:/path/to/my_project.git
git push origin master
```

(Thanks Josh Lindsey for client side)

after Client, do on Server this commands:

```
cd /srv/git/project_dir
chmod -R g+w objects/ refs/
```

If got this error after git pull:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch. Please specify which branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for details

git pull <remote> <branch>
If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

git branch --set-upstream new origin/<branch>
```

try:

```
git push -u origin master
```

It will help.

Answer (score 7):

You have to add [at least one file](http://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F) to the repository before committing, e.g. [`.gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Comment: I guess the way I'm trying to use it is to add the files initially from my client, since that's where I write the code.  Is that conceptually out of place in git?  Do I need to commit on the client first and then push to the server?

Answer (score 4):

@Josh Lindsey already answered perfectly fine. But I want to add some information since I often use ssh.

Therefore just change:

```
git remote add origin youruser@yourserver.com:/path/to/my_project.git
```

to:

```
git remote add origin ssh://youruser@yourserver.com/path/to/my_project
```

Note that the colon between domain and path isn't there anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I am aware there are existing answers which solves the problem. For those who are new to git, As of 02/11/2021, The default branch in git is `"main"` not `"master"` branch, The command will be

```
git push -u origin main
```

Comment: It is still an ongoing process, seems to apply to new repositories on GitHub https://github.com/github/renaming and GitLab already https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/03/10/new-git-default-branch-name/

Answer (score 2):

When you have a local git repo and want to add origin on this existing repo:

```
git remote add origin ssh://myserver.com/path/to/project
git pull origin main --allow-unrelated-histories
git push -u origin main
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up the remote repository on your client:

```
git remote add origin ssh://myserver.com/path/to/project
```

Comment: I ran that command, but a "git push origin master" still results in a "failed to push some refs".

I tried doing a "git pull origin master" and received a "couldn't find remote ref master".

Comment: I'm not sure whether it makes a difference, but my remote repositories are created with `git --bare init` as @Josh Lindsey recommends.

Comment: i had the same issue "failed to push some refs"...  trying to push master branch from a repo to one i created...  then i noticed the source doesn't have a master branch - make sure the branch you are trying to push exists :)

Answer (score 0):

Run below command

```
git config --local -e
```

change entry of

```
url = git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

to

```
url = https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run into the incident as mentioned by @dangerous-dev but you have a local default branch called `master` and a remote one called `main` push it using:

```
git push -u origin master:main
```

respectively using the long version:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master:main
```