# fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/home/username/git/myrepo.git/./objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Permission denied

Tags: git

I have been having trouble with this error message and I don't understand the proper solution to fix it or go about debugging it. I have googled the error in various forms but no real solution has presented itself. I am assuming it's an issue with permissions but I don't really know how to check or what I should check for.

I have a server running Ubuntu 11.10 and I'm basically trying to make the initial commit to my git repo from my development machine. I'm running as root. Should I be running as the user?

**Repo creation on server:**

```
$ cd /home/username/git
$ mkdir myrepo.git
$ cd myrepo.git/
$ git --bare init
```

**Repo creation  on development machine:**

```
Goto rails project directory first
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "initial commit"
$ bundle pack
$ git add Gemfile.lock vendor/cache
$ git commit -m "bundle gems"
$ git remote add origin ssh://username@server.com/home/username/git/myrepo.git
$ git push origin master
```

**Error:**

```
fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/home/username/git/myrepo.git/./objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Permission denied
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://username@server.com/home/username/git/myrepo.git'
```

**My .git/config file:**

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://username@server.com/home/username/git/myrepo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Similar question:
[How do I do an initial push to a remote repository with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337281/how-do-i-do-an-initial-push-to-a-remote-repository-with-git?rq=1)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It sounds like you have file in the git repo owned by root.  Since you're ssh'ing in as 'username' to do the push, the files must be writable by username.  The easiest thing is probably to create the repo as the user, and use the same user to do your pushes.  Another option is to create a group, make everything writable by the group, and make your user a member of that group.

Comment: Yep, this worked for me. I switched to the user that I created my "git" folder in, and made a directory for my repo. Went into the directory and ran "git --bare init". Then pushed to it from my windows machine, and it worked!

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales What would be helpful?

Comment: @DonBranson how to create the group, how to add users to the group, how to make the directory writable by the group.

Comment: @BrianD - search for those, because i'm sure they're already answered on superuser, serverfault, or add ubuntu, for example.

Comment: fair enough... here's some hints tho: groups are listed in `/etc/group`. add user to groups: https://superuser.com/a/95976/636934 .  change the owner of the folder to the group (`chown`) and change permissions on the folder (`chmod`).

Answer (score 27):

Ok, I figured it out. The issue was that I didn't have the correct permissions set for myrepo.git and the parent directory git.

As root I logged into the server and used:

```
$ chown username /home/username/git
```

This then returns drwxrwxr-x 4 username root 4096 2012-10-30 15:51 /home/username/git with the following:

```
$ ls -ld /home/username/git
```

I then make a new directory for myrepo.git inside git:

```
$ mkdir myrepo.git
$ ls -ld myrepo.git/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-10-30 18:41 myrepo.git/
```

but it has the user set to root, so I change it to username the same way as before.

```
$ chown username myrepo.git/
$ ls -ld myrepo.git/
drwxr-xr-x 2 username root 4096 2012-10-30 18:41 myrepo.git/
```

I then sign out of root and sign into server as username:

Inside git directory:

```
$ cd myrepo.git/
$ git --bare init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/username/git/myrepo.git/
```

On local machine:

```
$ git remote add origin      
ssh://username@server.com/home/username/git/myrepo.git
$ git push origin master
```

SUCCESS!

Hopefully this comes in handy for anyone else that runs into the same issue in the future!

Resources

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/unix-or-linux-commands-for-changing-user-rights.html
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-chmod-and-chown-command/

Comment: Extremely helpful! thanks for going through it step by step so that I could pinpoint my problem.

Comment: still cant push

Answer (score 3):

It would seem like your user doesn't have permission to write to that directory on the server. Please make sure that the permissions are correct. The user will need write permissions on that directory.

Comment: What do correct permissions look like for this type of situation?

Comment: Depends. Maybe `chmod 660 <that directory>`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Don Branson,I solve my problem.I think next time i should use this code when i build my repo on server:

```
root@localhost:~#mkdir foldername
root@localhost:~#cd foldername
root@localhost:~#git init --bare
root@localhost:~#cd ../
root@localhost:~#chown -R usergroup:username foldername
```

And on client,i user this

```
$ git remote add origin git@servername:/var/git/foldername
$ git push origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the principal issues with pushing to a GIT is that the material you push will appear as your material, and will block submissions from other people on a team.  As a GIT repository administrator, you will have to manage the hooks to prevent Alice's push from blocking Bob from pushing.   To do that, you will want to ensure that your developers all belong to a group, lets call it 'developers' and that the repository is owned by root:developers, and then add this to the hooks/post-update script:

```
sudo chown -R root:developers $GIT_DIR
sudo chmod -R g+w $GIT_DIR
```

That will make it so that team members are able to push to the repository without stepping on each other's toes.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to do this one (through root access) - "chmod -R 777 /home/username/git"

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by giving permission to the user on each of the directories that you're using, like so:

```
sudo chown user /home/user/git
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is that the git server you are pushing to is down/crashed, and the solution lies in restarting the git server.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (WINDOWS 10), it was Microsoft Defender (I just switch from another antivirus to Defender).

I just put my C:\Users\USERNAME\PROJECT-PATH.git\objects\pack in exclusion list and magic. :)

> WINDOWS 10 / VISUAL STUDIO 2019 or GIT FOR WINDOWS