# Can't edit files in '/var/www/' - Already followed a lot of tutorials

Tags: php, file-permissions

I'm trying to edit a PHP open source project, and I put it in /var/www to view the updates in real time using localhost. It works, but when I try to update one file of the project in `Sublime Text` I receive the following error:

```
Unable to save /var/www/howtoelementaryos/global.php
Error: unable to create tmp file in /var/www/howtoelementaryos
```

I want know what I can do to solve this problem, because I already followed these tutorials:

1. https://superuser.com/questions/378412/editing-files-in-var-www
2. [Git unable to create file permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077605/git-unable-to-create-file-permission-denied)
3. https://askubuntu.com/questions/348427/cant-save-files-in-var-www-using-lamp-installed-with-tasksel
4. [fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/home/username/git/myrepo.git/./objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146992/fatal-unable-to-create-temporary-file-home-username-git-myrepo-git-objects)

And none of these helped me. **Summarizing, what I can do to solve this issue?**

### Edit:

**stat /var/www:**

```
  File: `/var/www'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 806h/2054d  Inode: 4202729     Links: 4
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (   33/www-data)   Gid: (   33/www-data)
Access: 2013-10-28 10:33:02.827949771 -0200
Modify: 2013-10-28 10:14:39.030751552 -0200
Change: 2013-10-28 10:33:02.827949771 -0200
 Birth: -
```

**stat /var/www/howtoelementaryos:**

```
  File: `/var/www/howtoelementaryos'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 806h/2054d  Inode: 4195910     Links: 4
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (   33/www-data)   Gid: (   33/www-data)
Access: 2013-10-28 10:33:35.244209685 -0200
Modify: 2013-10-28 10:09:49.724196121 -0200
Change: 2013-10-28 10:33:02.831949803 -0200
 Birth: -
```

Comment: Could You show an output of `stat /var/www`, please? And `stat /var/www/howtoelementaryos`.

Comment: u using wamp or xamp?

Comment: So, what are your current groups and what are the permissions of `/var/www` and the subdirectories of it?

Comment: This probably belongs at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Okay, updating question. Far I know, I'm using LAMP

Comment: You have an error, when you want to save files with Sublime Text, but you are searching for tutorials and tag this question with `git`. Where does `git` come in in your try to save something with Sublime text?

Comment: Because this is a project that I cloned with a git. When I posted this question I don't know if the error can be with permissions, git, or both.

Comment: So what are your permissions in this directory? You can find out with `ls -l`

Comment: Go to one directory below your project root and do sudo chmod -R 775 proj. Enter your password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to one directory below your project root and do `sudo chmod -R 775 proj`, where proj is the name of your project root. Enter your password.