# Can't Clone Repo - No Such File or Directory (tmp_pack_XXXXXX)

Tags: git

This is a strange issue that started happening today. I was using VS code to push and pull changes from the remote repo, no issues. Suddenly I started running into issues where syncing / pulling would result in an error in the git output:

> Unable to create temporary file
> "/LOCALREPO/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX": No such file or
> directory

I ultimately ended up deleting my local repo and decided to clone it down again, but am getting the same error. I am at a loss as to what the source of this error is or how it came about in the first place.

I am on git version 2.20.1.windows.1

Comment: Is it possible you don't have enough disk space available? "Unable to create" looks like either disk space or permission shenanigans, but I'm not so sure about it

Comment: Plenty of space - I also noticed that when I run "mkdir DIRNAME" it gives a "Could not find file: "DirName"" error as well, which doesn't make sense to me. 

T

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/home/username/git/myrepo.git/./objects/pack/tmp\_pack\_XXXXXX': Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146992/fatal-unable-to-create-temporary-file-home-username-git-myrepo-git-objects)

Answer (score 1):

> Can't Clone Repo - No Such File or Directory (tmp_pack_XXXXXX)

The reason of this issue may be the corruption of the Windows file system cache. In this case, we could try to execute following command:

```
git config --global core.fscache false
```

Then, we could try to clone the code from the remote repo and we could  turned fscache back.