# Failed to push some refs when using push

Tags: git, github

I create a repository in Github and on my local machine I ran the code:

```
git init
git branch -m main
git remote add origin https://github.com/.../Project.git
git push -u origin main
```

Instead of using `master` branch I want to use `main` branch.

When running `git push -u origin main` I get the error:

```
failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/.../Project.git'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your local repo empty? I had to add a commit to run git push successfully.

Comment: It is not empty but I understood now that I first need to add some files and commit then before pushing. Now it is working.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337281/how-do-i-do-an-initial-push-to-a-remote-repository-with-git

Comment: That final message (`failed to push some refs...`) is a *summary* of the actual error(s), which all come *before* that line. That line itself is only interesting in that it means "please look above at previous lines".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your local repo empty?

In this case, you need to add a file and commit it.

```
1. Run notepad test.txt (Windows) or touch test.txt (Mac)
2. Save the file.
3. git add . 
4. git commit -m "Initial commit"
5. git push -u origin main
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't think you're doing anything necessarily wrong, persay. Git just doesn't know where to begin tracking between your local and the remote, because its a new repo (I assume). And you haven't initialised the remote yet. Try:

```
    git pull --rebase origin main
    git push origin main
```

Maybe do a `git push -u origin main` first. And make a copy of your source directory, just in case anything goes wrong so you don't lose your uncommitted code.

Whenever I am making a new repo on github, I use their website to create the repo first, then do a git clone to put the empty repo into my home directory. That way there is none of this nonsense when I go to make my first commit!

Comment: I like your last paragraph. Git clone makes sense to get the remote repo.