# Git GUI fails to identify bare repository while TortoiseGit succeeds

Tags: git, git-gui, git-bare

While I understand the [difference between a bare and non-bare](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72116221/2597758) Git repositories, I am puzzled by how a bare repository is not identified as a valid repository by git-gui (despite [successful push via Git Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2337373/2597758)), while TortoiseGit has no issue identifying it as such (right-click inside `Y:\as` > `TortoiseGit` > `Repo-browser`):

[image: TortoiseGit with bare repo]

Git Gui, on the other hand responds to the same exact `Y:\as` path with an error:

[image: Git Gui error Not a Git repository]

This is the same Git Gui that came with the official Git distribution:

[image: Git Gui version]

**Any idea why is?
Is this a bug? as designed?**

BTW, git-gui has no issue browsing the **working directory** matching same exact push/repo:

[image: git-gui on working directory]

Comment: Works as designed. Git GUI is primarily intended to stage files and create commits. Without a working tree, that's not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The screen capture you posted shows `gitk`, a GUI frontend to `git log` which will indeed work on any kind of repository -- bare or non bare. It is a tool independant from `git-gui` which can be run on its own, by simply invoking `gitk` from a terminal, or by double-clicking a shortcut if you have one.

From the view you show in your capture: you can see that you have a `Help > About gitk` entry in the menu.

Since you mention `git gui`, I imagine you are used to accessing this view by first running `git gui`, then selecting `Repository > Visualize [my branch]'s History` (or `Repository > Visualize All Branch History`)

---

`git-gui` itself, on the other hand, is geared towards editing your *index* (the files you stage or unstage before committing) by comparing it to your *working tree* (files on disk), and this requires a non-bare repository, which is why you get the error you mention when you try to target a bare repository.

---

Additionally, when invoking `gitk` from the command line, you can add almost any option you would pass to `git log` :

```
gitk                        # history of your active branch
gitk HEAD @{u}              # combined history of active branch + upstream
gitk foo bar origin/baz     # combined history of these 3 branches
gitk --all                  # combined history of all branches
gitk --follow -- that/file  # display only commits that modify that/file
gitk -G 'that word'         # filter history using one of the pickaxe options
# etc ...
```

you may also change these `git log` options on an active gitk window by going to `View > Edit view ... [F4]` and setting the options in the graphical window you see.

Comment: True. `git-gui` indeed invokes `gitk` when I select 'Visualize All Branch History'.

Answer (score 1):

> Additionally, when invoking `gitk` from the command line, you can add almost any option you would pass to `git log`.

Then make sure to use Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), if you are on Windows, as it is the case for this question:

See [commit 99e70f3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99e70f3077a585ed32f37b8ecc863083796d3e72) (08 May 2023) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit 7dd272e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7dd272eca153058da2e8d5b9960bbbf0b4f0cbaa) (24 Jan 2023) by [Nico Rieck (`gix`)](https://github.com/gix).
See [commit bb5cb23](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb5cb23daf751790950ff9f761f8884e21c88d00) (24 Jan 2023) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 29b8a3f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/29b8a3f49d3c521431650b670fa2fbcd9ad571b3), 15 May 2023)</sup>

> ### [`gitk`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7dd272eca153058da2e8d5b9960bbbf0b4f0cbaa): escape file paths before piping to git log
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Nico Rieck</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> We just started piping the file paths via `stdin` instead of passing them via the command-line, to avoid running into command-line limitations.
>
> However, since we now pipe the file paths, we need to take care of special characters.
>
> This fixes [`git-for-windows/git` issue 2293](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2293) ("`gitk` path filter fails with backslashes").